# call servlet when radio button is clicked

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to call servlet when radio button is clicked, how can I make it?

**EDIT**

I tried to add URL to servlet in javascript function like this

```
$.post( "ParentManagementServlet", "isActivated");
```

and like this

```
 $.post(<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/ParentManagementServlet"%>, "isActivated");
```

and like this

```
  $.post("/ParentManagementServlet?isActivated=true");
```

but both does not call servlet!

here's the url mapping of the servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ParentManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ps.iugaza.onlineinfosys.servlets.ParentManagementServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ParentManagementServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ParentManagementServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I usually add the servlet through its name, but I read that it's better to get the servlet absolute path form servlet context.

Comment: @smas, @Bozho, @Jigar Joshi, I tried to add URL to servlet like this 
$.post( "ParentManagementServlet", "isActivated"); and like this $.post(<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/ParentManagementServlet"%>, "isActivated"); , but both does not call servlet!

Comment: @Alaa: show part with servlet mapping from your web.xml and put your code in question not in comment

Comment: @smas, ok, just a minute

Comment: $.post(uri, data) - data - must be an object (e.g. $.post("/path/to/your/servlet", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );)

Comment: @Alaa: you haven't servlet-mapping part in your web.xml. After you add this part test your servlet. Enter URL in browser and check if then it works

Comment: @smas, I add the url mapping part.

Comment: @ninja, I make like this ,$.post(<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/ParentManagementServlet"%>, {isActivated:"true"});  , but not working too.

Comment: What does Firebug say? What does `success:{}` or `error:{}` handlers of `$.post` say? Is it the URL which returns 404 or is it just the `$.post` which doesn't get called? Please learn how to debug code. What line get executed and what not? What HTTP request get sent and what not?

Comment: @BlausC,I make alert before this line, it works , and another alert after it, but doesn't work, so ${post} doesn't call the servlet, about fireBug, here's what returns $ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $.post("/ParentManagementServlet?isActivated=true");

Comment: @BlausC, Does that happen because I am calling it through js function?

Comment: It woooooooooooooooooooooorks I make like this
document.location.href = "<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/ParentManagementServlet?isActivated=true"%>";
document.getElementById("stdActivationForm").submit();

Comment: Oh boy.. You were just stabbing and running headlessly around in the dark. Please take time to buy/read a good book/tutorial. By the way, my nickname is BalusC, not BlausC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

> *about fireBug, here's what returns $ is not defined*

The `$` is definied by [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You've apparently not declared it in your page. jQuery is a JS library and not something already builtin the browser or something.

Put the following line **before** any other `<script>` in your `<head>`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

(you can of course also download and serve a copy from your own domain)

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

#### See also:

- [Update current page with Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet) - contains several complete jQuery-Servlet examples

Comment: That's the start of jQuery library :) many thanx for the "See also" link, sorry for writing ur nickname incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax. For example, with jQuery:

```
...onclick="invokeServlet()"

function invokeServlet() {
    $.post("/path/to/servlet", params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To call servlet in time when user select radio (without submit button) use:

- Add appropriate mapping to your Servlet - Bind some URL to servlet.
- use onselect attribute to call javascript function, which will redirect to the URL

example:

```
<input type ="radio" Value="blah blah" onSelect="yourFunction()"/>
```

In other situation the idea is the same: bind Servlet, choose event which will be trigger the servlet